# Avoid evaluating the function with same input multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, solver

I am trying to utilise scipy.optimise.fsolve for solving a function. I noticed that the function is evaluated with the same value multiple times in the beginning and the end of the iteration steps. For example when the following code is evaluated:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def yy(x):
    print(x)
    return x**2+9*x+20

y = fsolve(yy,22.)

print(y)
```

The following output is obtained:

```
[ 22.]
[ 22.]
[ 22.]
[ 22.00000033]
[ 8.75471707]
[ 4.34171812]
[ 0.81508685]
[-1.16277103]
[-2.42105811]
[-3.17288066]
[-3.61657372]
[-3.85653348]
[-3.96397335]
[-3.99561793]
[-3.99984826]
[-3.99999934]
[-4.]
[-4.]
[-4.]
```

Therefore the function is evaluated with 22. three times, which is unnecessary.

This is especially annoying when the function requires substantial evaluation time. Could anyone please explain this and suggest how to avoid this issue?

Comment: One of the arguments is [`fprime`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) which is described as *"A function to compute the Jacobian of func with derivatives across the rows. By default, the Jacobian will be estimated."*. I wonder if the first few calls are during an approximation of the Jacobian for the first couple steps.

Comment: But, why would it use the same variable? Should not it change the value for evaluating a Jacobian?

Comment: Looks like my guess was wrong, I wrote a Jacobian for your function `def y_p(x): return 2*x + 9` and passed that as `fprime=y_p` and it still evaluates the `22.` value several times. Strange, I don't have a guess why it's doing that.

Comment: Looks like the details of these calls is buried in MINPACK code: https://www.math.utah.edu/software/minpack/minpack/hybrd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first evaluation is done only to check the shape and data type of the output of the function. Specifically, `fsolve` calls `_root_hybr` which contains [the line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L212)

```
shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
```

Naturally, `_check_func` [calls the function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L26):

```
res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
```

Since only the shape and data type are retained from this evaluation, the solver will be calling the function with the value `x0` again when actual root finding process begins.

The above accounts for **one** extraneous call (out of two). I did not track down the other one, but it's conceivable that the FORTRAN code does some kind of preliminary check of its own. This sort of thing happens when algorithms written long ago get wrapped over and over again.

If you really want to save these two evaluations of expensive function yy, one way is to compute the value yy(x0) separately and store it. For example:

```
def yy(x):
    if x == x0 and y0 is not None:
       return y0
    print(x)
    return x**2+9*x+20

x0 = 22.
y0 = None
y0 = yy(x0)
y = fsolve(yy, x0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised an important reason for this issue is that fsolve is not meant for such a problem: Solvers should be chosen wisely :)

```
multivariate: fmin, fmin_powell, fmin_cg, fmin_bfgs, fmin_ncg
nonlinear: leastsq
constrained: fmin_l_bfgs_b, fmin_tnc, fmin_cobyla
global: basinhopping, brute, differential_evolution
local: fminbound, brent, golden, bracket
n-dimensional: fsolve
one-dimensional: brenth, ridder, bisect, newton
scalar: fixed_point
```